# get value from nested dictionary (from plist file) in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swift2

[image]

i am facing a problem to get the values from my plist file. I want to get the data of two marked red rectangles. The flow of this is :

i can get the three key values from root dictionary, but i want to go to marked rectangle of the

```
TestableSummaries
```

which is an array.Than it has a dictionary

```
Test
```

and so on.

Currently i can get the values of

```
 TestableSummaries
```

The code i use is given below:

```
 var componentArray: [AnyObject]
    var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
    if let dict = myDict {

        var val = dict.valueForKeyPath("TestableSummaries")!
        print(val)
    }
```

but i can't go to the deep of TestableSummaries. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: TestableSummaries is your first dictionary so, you already have when you call `myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)` myDict is your `TestableSummaries`dictionary so you need to use let arrayOfDict = dict.objectForKey("Test")

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks but its not working. My root has 3 dict and "TestableSummaries" is one of them. and i want to go deep of the value of TestableSummaries for ex. i want to get the values of red rectangle of TestableSummaries.

Comment: TestableSummaries is not a dictionary is an array??

Comment: @ReinierMelian it is an array itselft, but key of root dictionary

Comment: Your structure of data is too complex, you can put your code on github to make a review and see if i can help you?

Comment: this `dict["TestableSummaries"][0][Tests][0]["Subtests"][0]["Subtests"][0]["Subtests"][0]`should get you to the first red arrow, but WHY, you should definitely change the way you handle data, cause this is not by far a good solution

Comment: I agree 4oby maybe you need review your solution @Helper

Comment: @4oby i want the test name and test status for a testing purpose actually